# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I run my pipeline in eclipse it runs fine. But when I export pipeline as jar file and run that I get below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
>   return a default Coder for ToTableRow/ParMultiDo(ToTableRow).out0
>   [PCollection]. Correct one of the following root causes:   No Coder
>   has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
>   Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Unable to provide a
>   Coder for com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow.   Building
>   a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.   See suppressed
>   exceptions for detailed failures.   Using the default output Coder
>   from the producing PTransform failed: Unable to provide a Coder for
>   com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow.   Building a Coder
>   using a registered CoderProvider failed.   See suppressed exceptions
>   for detailed failures.
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:444)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.getCoder(PCollection.java:257)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.finishSpecifying(PCollection.java:106)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.finishSpecifyingInput(TransformHierarchy.java:147)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:513)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:473)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:297)
>           at com.X.pubsub.to.bq.Y.main(Y.java:107)

At line 107 in my code I am doing a `BigQueryIO.writeTableRows`:

```
PCollection<TableRow> tableRow = streamData.apply("ToTableRow",ParDo.of(new PrepData.ToTableRow())); //String to TableRow


        tableRow.apply("WriteToBQ",
                BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .to(String.format("%1$s.%2$s",bqDataSet, bqTable))
                .withSchema(schema)
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

Comment: after using maven shaded plugin this worked fine.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind posting your fix as an answer?